# ObjectOutputStream IOException / timeout on Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, stream

I am developing a real-time Android application and have an issue with detecting errors on an `ObjectOutputStream` which is connected to a `TCP` network `Socket`.  I am calling `writeObject` followed by a `flush` on the stream as normal, however when the receiving node unexpectedly dies I need to know about it right away (within seconds).  Unfortunately when the node goes down the server's call to `writeObject` and `flush` do not throw `IOException`s and instead succeed.

I am assuming there is internal buffering that takes place with these calls and that is the reason for its success?  Is there any way to know when a node is down via `writeObject` or other means after a `Socket` has been successfully created?

It is worth noting that the TCP `Socket`s are left open for performance reasons, so setting a timeout on `connect` for every `writeObject` is not possible.

Comment: Show your code. It's easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when the receiving node unexpectedly
>   dies I need to know about it right
>   away (within seconds)

You can't. TCP doesn't tell you. It doesn't know. It is busy doing buffering and retrying. It will wventually time out, and if you do a write after that you will get the exception. There is no control whatsoever over how long that takes.